Extract Certain Data from a Json File to CSV in Python
I have a json file that has employee data in it, see a snippet below:
{
"confirmMessage": null,
"meta": null,
"workers": [
    {
        "person": {
            "legalName": {
                "formattedName": "LastName, FirstName"
            },
            "militaryClassificationCodes": []
        },
        "workAssignments": [
            {
                "actualStartDate": "2020-01-01",
                "customCountryInputs": []
            }
        ],
        "workerID": {
            "idValue": "XXXXXXXXX"
        }
    },
    {
        "person": {
            "legalName": {
                "formattedName": "LastName, FirstName"
            },
            "militaryClassificationCodes": []
        },
        "workAssignments": [
            {
                "actualStartDate": "2020-01-01",
                "customCountryInputs": []
            }
        ],
        "workerID": {
            "idValue": "XXXXXXXXX"
        }
    },

What I am looking to do is export the formattedName and actualStartDate to a csv file. I have tried multiple ways of iterating through the information, and cannot get it to come out in a clean format. See example below:
Output
What I desire is a 2 column csv file with the headers of formattedName and actualStartDate.
This is the code I am using to open the files and write to the csv:
def csvDump():
    count = 0
    for filename in os.listdir('./Anniversaries/'):
        print(filename)
        with open('AnniversaryOutput.csv', 'a') as f:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
            with open('./Anniversaries/' + filename) as json_file:
                data = json.load(json_file)
                employeeData = data['workers']
                for emp in employeeData:    
                    if count == 0:
                        header = emp.keys()
                        csv_writer.writerow(header)
                        count+=1
                csv_writer.writerow(emp.values())
            f.close()
    return()

This results in the above output image. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

csv_writer.writerow(emp.values()) should be inside the loop. Since you put it outside the loop, you only write the last row.

You don't need f.close(). That's done automatically by with.

The values in emp are nested dictionaries. You need to make a list of the specific values in those dictionaries that you want to put in the CSV.

E.g. csv_writer.writerow([emp["person"]["legalName"]["formattedName"], emp["workAssignments"][0]["actualStartDate"]])

What do you want to do if there are multiple work assignments? Or none?

Excellent, this worked perfectly, thank you! As for as multiple/no work assignments, that is not a case that is possible, but I appreciate you thinking about it.

You're writing emp.keys() as the header, meaning that the CSV header will consist of "person", "workAssignments" and "workerID".
Next, you're writing emp.values() as the row. This will essentially dump the JSON into the CSV cells.
You have to select the exact values that you need from the JSON instead of writing all the values.

def csvDump():
    count = 0

    # Initialize the writer only once to avoid many OS calls
    with open('AnniversaryOutput.csv', 'w') as out_buffer:
         # Specify the field names
         writer = csv.DictWriter(out_buffer, fieldnames=('formattedName', 'actualStartDate'))
         # Write the header
         writer.writeheader()

         for filename in os.listdir('./Anniversaries/'):
             print(filename)
             with open('./Anniversaries/' + filename) as json_file:
                 data = json.load(json_file)
                 employeeData = data['workers']
                 # Loop over employees
                 for employee in employeeData:
                     # Extract name and start date according to the expected schema
                     formatted_name = employee["legalName"]["formattedName"]
                     actual_start_date = employee["workAssignments"][0]["actualStartDate"]  # I assumed that there's only one item in workAssignments
                     writer.writerow(
                         {
                             "actualStartDate": actual_start_date,
                             "formattedName": formatted_name
                         }
                     )



fixed missing word
